# Ember.js Model architecture with roles and states

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am currently diving into Ember.js. I have started a new project which should handle todo tasks.

However I have some problems in translating the database architecture and/or OOP architecture to an ember model architecture.

What I would like to have is:

A task which has the following attributes:

- `id`
- `title`
- `state` ('open', 'closed')
- `editor`
- `creator`
- `createdAt`
- `modifiedAt`

The point were I stuck is:

- how to abstract the state (in OOP I would create a struct for this)
- how to abstract the editor/creator thing

I would be glad if anyone would have a suggestion for me since the Ember.js documentation only covers basic use cases and is lack of things like states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually Ember is OOP, just to mention that first!

Now lets talk about your `editor`/`editor`. I would recommend to basically create another model `person`, and then you could so something like this:

```
creator: belongsTo('person'),
author: belongsTo('person'),
```

You don't need an inverse relationship so this will basically just work, as long you don't want to find all `task`'s one person has created or so.

For the `state` you basically have three ways:

1. What I recommend is to use another model for this, and use a `belongsTo` relationship. But this is not a good way if you want to execute different code on different states. But the best if you want to have a dropdown or so to select the `state`.
2. You could just sent the strings.
3. You could sent integers and have somewhere a mapping to the values. Like an object or an map, to map the integers to the strings.